# Forward incoming call upon 32011 warning

Tags: twilio

I want to forward a call when it can not be completed due to the 32011 warning.  The call should ring 2 numbers simultaneously until one answers.  Can this be done and does anyone have sample code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Disaster Recovery URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking#disaster-recovery) if your Origination URI encounters a 32011 - Error communicating with your SIP communications infrastructure.

Keep in mind, the call will be priced at the [Programmable Voice pricing](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-) when the disaster recovery URL is hit, vs the Elastic SIP Trunking pricing.

You can follow the TwiML [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html) to Sim Ring multiple phones or use Studio and the [Connect Call to Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call), Connect to multiple numbers to do the same.